# Split long html into smaller pieces

Tags: php, laravel

I need to split long html into smaller pieces with respect to tags and inline styles.
E.g. given html

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="font-size:12px;">Some long string here</td>
      <td style="color: red">Some short string here</td>
      <td style="font-weight: bold">Some specific string here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The source of the problem: I've a long html over 50k of chars and I need to translate it via google translate api which has a max limit of 5000 chars per request.

Comment: Have you tried anything that you can show us that doesn't work, or partially works?

Comment: Only translate the text nodes then.

Comment: How to properly extract whole whole text from html nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just splitting it, you can use [`str_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and iterate the array:

```
$chunks = str_split($html, 5000);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    // $chunk var is up to 5000 chars long
}
```

But before, you might want to consider sending it without the HTML part:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$text = "";

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element) {
    $text .= $element->textContent . "\n";
}
```

Then using the split operation on the `$text` variable.

For both combined, let's say your input variable is `$html`:

```
function htmlToText($html)
{
    $text = "";

    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element) {
        $text .= $element->textContent . "\n";
    }

    return $text;
}

$chunks = str_split(htmlToText($html), 5000);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    // dispatch the API operation over $chunk
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried you solution but unfortunately it does not very helpfull for elements like this `<div>1. <a href="#">Element</a></div>` - if I run your code it will return `1. Element`. Once i translate this phrase how will I replace this phrase with translated one in original html?

Comment: @AndreyA If you want you can send the text including the HTML tags. Just do `$chunks = str_split($html, 5000);` without the `htmlToText` function